# spring mvc RequestMapping annotation consume configuration does not work

Tags: spring-mvc, content-type

spring mvc controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Result<String> create(@Valid @RequestBody CouponModel model) {
     //...
}
```

First I call this api

```
curl -X POST -d 'couponName=foo&couponPrice=30&...'  'http://localhost:8080/coupons'
Error 415 Unsupported Media Type
```

Then I modify `@RequestMapping` annotation to support `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Content Type

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "application/json"})
```

Then call again, still

```
Error 415 Unsupported Media Type
```

Why this `consumes` attribute does not work?

Comment: You don't send a `Content-Type` header.

Comment: -d, --data <data>
              (HTTP)  Sends  the  specified  data  in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has
              filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using  the  content-
              type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: I see. But then you don't need `@RequestBody`.

Comment: so if has `@RequestBody`, it will only receive `application/json` request, and ignore `consumes` settings. Is it ?

Comment: You can use `consumes`, but Spring automatically maps form data to the model if you don't have `@RequestBody`. Is `create()` mapped to `/coupons`?

Comment: but actually if I remove `@RequestBody` it will have another error: `Error 400 Bad Request`. And I don't know why is so?

Comment: If you remove `@RequestBody` then I assume you also have to remove `consumes`. Did you check the actual request btw.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108265/discussion-between-zhuguowei-and-zeroflagl).